# Build a graph structure in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm modelling the type information of a relational database. I would like to build the following graph:

1. The vertices are tables.
2. An edge exists from table A to table B for every column in A which is a foreign key to B.

This is the initial data I have for building the graph.

```
newtype TableName = TableName T.Text
newtype ColName = ColName T.Text
newtype ColType = ColType T.Text

type DBInfo = H.HashMap TableName TableInfo
type TableInfo = H.HashMap ColName ColInfo
data ColInfo = CISimple ColType
             -- Forms the basis for building the graph
             | CIFKey ColType TableName -- col type, referenced table

getDBInfo :: IO (DBInfo)
```

These are the types of the graph structure I'm expecting.

```
data SafeColInfo = SCISimple ColType 
                 -- This captures an edge between two tables
                 | SCIFKey ColType SafeTableInfo
type SafeTableInfo = H.HashMap TableName SafeColInfo
type SafeDBInfo = ..
```

I would like to write this function :

```
convDBInfo :: DBInfo -> Either String SafeDBInfo
```

`convDBInfo` should build the above graph. The information about `t` in any foreign key `(CIFKey ctype t)` can be found by looking up `t` in `DBInfo`. If it is not found, the input data is inconsistent and is an error.

This is fairly straightforward in an imperative language with references. However, I can't think of a way to solve this in Haskell. As I understand, this looks like a good fit for the 'Tying the knot' paradigm, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. How do I write this function?

Comment: Sorry, what should `convDBInfo` do?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Edited to add the information.

Comment: If you know there won’t be an error, why does it need to return an `Either`?

Comment: A `lookup` of `t` from `DBInfo` could be a failure (`Maybe TableInfo`) even though it wouldn't happen.

Comment: Why not use HashMap's `foldWithKey`?

Comment: Rephrased the question. @Arnon, I can't follow. What is the idea?

Comment: @svr - you use `foldWithKey` to traverse over the HashMap and your custom function (that you call with `fold`) transforms each element into a safe element accordingly. That way, when you finish your fold you have a new structure that is safe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can tie a knot the following way:

```
convDBInfo :: DBInfo -> SafeDBInfo
convDBInfo dbi = safeDbi where
  safeDbi = H.map (H.map go) dbi
  go (CIFKey colName tblName) = SCIFKey colName $ safeDbi H.! tblName
  go (CISimple colName)       = SCISimple colName
```

We get `safeDbi` by mapping over the column entries in the input. The important point is that we look up the tables from `safeDbi` in the definition of `go`, so the tables in `SCIFKey`-s will be from the resulting hashmap.

Example:

```
foo :: DBInfo
foo = H.fromList [
  ("table1", H.fromList [
       ("col1", CIFKey "a" "table2")
       ]),
  ("table2", H.fromList [
       ("col2", CIFKey "b" "table1")
       ])
  ]

bar = convDBInfo foo
SCIFKey _ tbl2 = (bar H.! "table1") H.! "col1"
SCIFKey name _ = tbl2 H.! "col2"
-- name == "b"
```

Note though that knotty data structures are often inconvenient to use, because they are indistinguishable from lazy infinite structures, so we have to give it extra thought when we'd like to print, serialize or compare them. Most of the time explicitly keyed graphs are easier to use, and not much worse performance wise.